# How to iteratively replace list items with dictionary values in python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

I'm trying to create an encoding/decoding function which takes an input string and switches each letter to the corresponding value in the dictionary Key by matching letter to a key.It's basically a ROT-13 cipher.

```
def Encode_Decode(A):
    A=list(A)
    for n in range(0,len(A),+1):
        if A[n]==Key.keys:
            map(Key.values(),A[n])


    print("This translates to: "+"".join(A))



Encode_Decode("Hello there")
```

I use a dictionary which assigns a key value in the alphabet to a letter 13 letters up

```
Key=    {'a':'n','b':'o','c':'p','d':'q','e':'r','f':'s',
'g':'t','h':'u','i':'v',
'j':'w','k':'x','l':'y','m':'z','n':'a',
'o':'b','p':'c','q':'d','r':'e'
,'s':'f','t':'g','u':'h','v':'i','w':'j',
'x':'k','y':'l','z':'m','A':'N',
'B':'O','C':'P','D':'Q','E':'R','F':'S',
'G':'T','H':'U','I':'V','J':'W',
'K':'X','L':'Y','M':'Z','N':'A','O':'B',
'P':'C','Q':'D','R':'E','S':'F',
'T':'G','U':'H','V':'I','W':'J',
'X':'K','Y':'L','Z':'M'}
```

Can anyone tell me why my function doesn't return a translated sentence?

Comment: use `for` loops properly, without indexing. BTW, what is `Key` and `Key.keys`?

Comment: `print A.translate(string.maketrans(*zip(*Key.items())))`

Comment: @Joran Beasley Wow, that's efficient!  What does `*zip(*Key.items())` do?The documentation for `str.maketrans` would have led me (probably incorrectly) to `str.maketrans(Key)`.

Comment: `d.items()` will give you a list of `[(key,val),(key,val),...]` ... then when you call `zip(*...)` that will give you a new pair of lists `[(key,key,key),(val,val,val)]` ... the star in front just unpacks it into the 2 arguments that string.maketrans expects ... doh cept I left part out :(

Comment: should be `string.maketrans(*map(''.join,zip(*Key.items())))`

Comment: @Joran Beasley Thanks for the explanation.  The part of the documentation that confuses me is this: "If there is only one argument, it must be a dictionary mapping Unicode ordinals (integers) or characters (strings of length 1) to Unicode ordinals, strings (of arbitrary lengths) or None. Character keys will then be converted to ordinals."  That made me wonder about `str.maketrans(Key)`.

Comment: it would probably work in newer versions of python ... im on 2.6 and it doesnt like just a dict

Answer (score 1):

This is not the only problem, but ... I think you want:

```
if A[n] in Key:
```

instead of

```
if A[n]==Key.keys:
```

Key is a confusing name for a dict, by the way.

I know this is merely a comment, not a complete answer, but I don't know how to format comments :)

Answer (score 1):

If *all* possible characters were in `Key`, you could just write this:

```
def Encode_Decode(A):
    A = map(Key.get, A)
    print("This translates to: "+"".join(A))
```

However, in your test string, there is a space, and `Key.get(' ')` returns `None`. `"".join(A)` will fail if there is a `None` in the sequence

You can fix that by passing a default argument to `Key.get`

```
def Encode_Decode(A):
    A = (Key.get(x, x) for x in A)
    print("This translates to: "+"".join(A))
```

`Key.get(x, x)` means if `x` isn't in the dictionary, just use `x` instead, so spaces and other characters will be unchanged